# Unpacking Comprehensed list without " ' " in f strings

Tags: python, mysql, list-comprehension, f-string

I'm trying to make a `sql query` with list comprehension. First I take a column names like this

```py
COLUMNS_ONE = ["id INT(6)", "firstname VARCHAR(30)"]
COLUMN_NAMES_ONE = [name.split(" ")[0] for name in COLUMNS_ONE]
print(COLUMN_NAMES_ONE)

>>> ["id", "firstname"]
```

Next I'm trying to make an `sql query` variable for `mysql` like this

```py
f"INSERT INTO {TABLE_NAMES[0]} ({*COLUMN_NAMES_ONE,}) VALUES (%s, %s)"
```

which throws

```py
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '('id', 'firstname')) VALUES (6, 'Marcel')' at line 1
```

saying that the `query` is inserted not like `(id, firstname)`, but `('id', 'firstname')`.
Is there a way to get rid of that `'` somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `join()` instead:

```
COLUMNS_ONE = ["id INT(6)", "firstname VARCHAR(30)"]
COLUMN_NAMES_ONE = [name.split(" ")[0] for name in COLUMNS_ONE]

f"INSERT INTO Table ({', '.join(COLUMN_NAMES_ONE)}) VALUES (%s, %s)"

# 'INSERT INTO Table (id, firstname) VALUES (%s, %s)'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join the list with `,` :

```
print(f"INSERT INTO Table ({', '.join(COLUMN_NAMES_ONE)}) VALUES (%s, %s)")
```